# Usage of "begehen"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Can one substitute *begehen*  with *gehen*? In the dict.cc it says "penetrate into sth". I am going to type a sentence with *begehen* and *gehen*.

> 1. Ich begehe das Gebäude.
> 2. Ich gehe in das Gebäude.

It has a lot of meanings and they are:

- a: to commit sth.

> Ein Mann in Newark, dem Staate Kalifornien hat seine Frau und seine Kinder erschossen und danach hat er Selbstmord begangen.

Can I also say *Selbstmord machen*? I heard a rapper by the name of Eko Fresh say "Mach Selbstmord, mach Selbstmord".

- b: to celebrate or to observe sth.

> Seine Schwester begeht ihren 24ten Geburtstag.

Comment: Your question is very hard to read when bilingual text, and examples are not formatted in any way. Please do take some time to read our [editing help on post formatting](http://german.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) *Begangen* is correct! You use *begehen* if someone commits something like a crime, or suicide

> eine Missetat begehen

And yes, you can say *Selbstmord machen*, but it sounds weird, too.
You should say

> Selbstmord begehen

b) It sounds really weird to me as a German. You won't say *einen Geburtstag begehen*.
You should say:

> einen Geburtstag feiern

Comment: Wenn man davon spricht, dass jemand einen Geburtstag begeht, ist das immer formell: die Queen begeht ihren Geburtstag, China begeht Maos 120. Geburtstag, etc.

Comment: Hmm, mag sein ich habe das in meinem ganzen Leben noch nie benutzt, aber man lernt ja nie aus !

Answer (score 2):

Man kann auch ein Gebäude begehen. Das bedeutet aber nicht nur es zu betreten, sondern es zu inspizieren, zB bei einer Abnahme.